# Why Checkbox checked attribute is not checking the form attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

[image]I have tried a lot but the react Check box checked is not working properly.There may be a common mistake That I am unable to figure out.I am trying to change the state of the react checkbox by using use state and changing the checked by of isAdmin by sending a boolean value to it but it is not working.

Pls Help !!!!!

Here is the Edit Screen where the checkbox is present.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Form, Button,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Message from '../components/Message';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import { getUserDetails } from '../actions/userActions';
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer';

const UserEditScreen = ({ match, history }) => {

  const userId = match.params.id

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const  [isAdmin,setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);
  const { loading, error, user } = userDetails;

  useEffect(()=>{
      if(!user.name || user._id !==userId){
          dispatch(getUserDetails(userId))
      }else{
          setName(user.name)
          setEmail(user.email)
          setIsAdmin(user.isAdmin)
      }
  }, [dispatch,userId,user])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
   
  }
  return (
      <>
          <Link to = '/admin/userlist' className='btn btn-dark my-3'>
              Go Back
          </Link>


          <FormContainer>
      <h1>Edit User</h1>
      {/* {message && <Message variant='danger'>{message}</Message>}
      {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}

      {loading && <Loader />} */}

{loading ? <Loader />: error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message> :(

<Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
<Form.Group controlId='name'>
  <Form.Label>Enter Name</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    type='text'
    placeholder='Enter Name'
    value={name}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setName(e.target.value);
    }}
  ></Form.Control>
</Form.Group>

<Form.Group controlId='email'>
  <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    type='email'
    placeholder='Enter Email'
    value={email}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    }}
  ></Form.Control>
</Form.Group>

<Form.Group className='py-3' controlId='isadmin' >
  <Form.Check
    label='If Admin then Check'
    id='useradmin'
    type='checkbox'
    checked={isAdmin}
    
     onChange={(e) => {
      setIsAdmin(e.target.checked); }}
  ></Form.Check>
</Form.Group>



<Button className='py-3' type='submit' variant='primary'>
  Update
</Button>
</Form>

)}  
    </FormContainer>
      </>
    
  );
};

export default UserEditScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight change required in your onChange handler

#### Current way

```
onChange={(e) => {setIsAdmin(e.target.checked); }}
```

#### Correct way

```
onChange={(e) => {setIsAdmin(e.target.value); }}
```

Here, `e` is the `event`, which in this case is `change`, `target` is the element that triggered the event, which in this case is the `Form.check`, and `value` is the value of the element. Thus you have to set your state (in this case `isAdmin`) with the value of that element.

Comment: I wanted to check only on those users that are admin but the checked property is not working.As  I am loading isAdmin Values from MongoDB. By Default the checked property should be false for those users that are not admin and true for admins since isAdmin passes a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the problem is with the checked property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider code like this.

```js
onChange={() => {
  setIsAdmin((prev) => !prev);
}}
```